# Binding to a Readonly property which returns another property in mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net, entity-framework, razor

Let's say I have an Entity with 3 properties **A, B, and C** of same **complex data-type**. Now I have defined another **not mapped, read-only** property **D** of the **same complex data-type**. Property **D** returns reference of any one of the three original properties **i.e. (A, B Or C)** depending on some internal logic. My question is -

NOW CAN I **BIND PROPERTY D** WITH AN EDITOR CONTROL OF AN EDIT PAGE IN A RAZOR VIEW?

If it is not possible then is there any work around?

(Note: I am using VB.NET as coding language).

Comment: You cannot. The `DefaultModelBinder` cannot set the value of read-only properties. But why would you want to users to edit a read-only property?

Comment: `NonMapped` & `readonly` marked property has never be able to assign in `DefaultModelBinder` instance. It requires other writable property to read its value & participate in model binding schema.

Comment: After much thinking I just dropped the read-only keyword and defined a set section of the not mapped property. It worked. Anyway, I decided to skip the whole thing as It's becoming complicated.